# Как реализовать появление блока при наведениии на svg path?

Tags: html, css, svg

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать появление блока, при наведении на path внутри sgv.
Есть sgv карта, внутри несколько path - области. При наведении на каждый район он закрашивается - всё ок.
Но как сделать так, чтоб при наведении еще и отобразился блок у которого стиль display:none;

Со ссылкой - без проблем:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
a:hover + .hide {
  display: block;
}
```

```
<a href="">Ссылка</a>
<div class="hide">123456789</div>
```

А вот с path никак получается.

Мой код с работающей ссылкой и не работающим svg - https://codepen.io/innocentDimon/pen/VwpLbMr?editors=1100

Comment: Всё таки отличается https://codepen.io/innocentDimon/pen/VwpLbMr

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/eYvNRVe отвечу комментарием - собираем массив и в него добавляем описание и собираем из массива svg и при наведении показываем инфомацию а при отведении скрываем

Answer (score 3):

Для реализации показа одного элемента при наведении на другой в данном случае совсем не обязательно использование JS. Стоит заметить, что любой элемент содержимого SVG, в том числе и `path` - это обычный элемент, который ничем не отличается от любого другого элемента содержимого всего HTML-документа.

Простой вариант CSS с использованием SVG-элемента `<foreignObject>`. Для того, чтобы сократить CSS код до одной строчки:

```
path:hover ~ foreignObject {}
```

заключаем элементы `path` и `foreignObject` для группировки в элемент `g`.

Пример:

```css
#map {
  margin: 0 auto; width: 500px;
}

#map svg {
  width: 100%; height: 250px;
  stroke: yellow; fill: green;
  background: aliceblue; border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

#one:hover {fill: red;}
#two:hover {fill: deepskyblue;}

.win__one {width: 120px; height: 40px; background: red;}
.win__two {width: 120px; height: 40px; background: deepskyblue;}

path {cursor: pointer; transition: all 0.5s;}
path:hover {transform: scale(1.05);}

foreignobject {
  display: none; opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

path:hover ~ foreignObject {
  display: block; opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="map">
<svg>
<g>

<g>
<path id="one" title="EnSO" d="M313.23,58.66L306.56,87.28L299.68,118.48L300.3,122.21L299.24,126.14L267.26,118.43L261.12,119.3L257.44,117.29L253.95,118.28L247.56,119.17L240.68,116.96L236.67,117.76L233.22,117.63L231.12,115.79L225.89,113.27L222.2,112.96L215.57,113.53L211.77,112.47L208.47,110.57L208.26,107.16L208.97,103.37L207.41,98.33L203.38,95.72L200.31,92.59L195.72,91.03L192.49,90.34L194.19,70.89L198.52,49.07L217.79,59.52L219.14,78.74L224.58,74.04L227.61,55.27L226.19,34.98L269.51,47.56z"/>
<foreignObject class="win__one">
<span>Окно EnSO</span>
</foreignObject>
</g>

<g>
<path id="two" title="RuSO" d="M299.24,126.14L301.91,131.28L304.11,133.69L304.17,137.26L301.92,139.8L298.48,145.04L294.56,151.7L290.12,155.29L286.7,159.8L285.82,163.34L288.45,165.54L289.06,168.74L286.18,174.71L276.58,214.43L276.56,214.49L227.74,202.25L159.29,181.87L158.03,168.07L170.35,146.42L179.28,122.31L192.49,90.34L195.72,91.03L200.31,92.59L203.38,95.72L207.41,98.33L208.97,103.37L208.26,107.16L208.47,110.57L211.77,112.47L215.57,113.53L222.2,112.96L225.89,113.27L231.12,115.79L233.22,117.63L236.67,117.76L240.68,116.96L247.56,119.17L253.95,118.28L257.44,117.29L261.12,119.3L267.26,118.43z"/>
<foreignObject class="win__two">
<span>Окно RuSO</span>
</foreignObject>
</g>

</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё верно. Именно так :)

Comment: @MaximLensky: а просто с HTML не так? Вот только Павел зачем-то каждый `<span>` обернул, а надо было именно весь HTML-блок обернуть в общий `<foreignobject >` один раз.

Comment: @MaximLensky: Это да - для реального сайта только JS.

Comment: @Sevastopol': я не про span-ы говорил, а про `<foreignobject>` - он может быть всего один, а вся HTML-разметка в нём, как обычно.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого примера я создал на бесплатном хосте сайтик без индэксного файла и залил на него json с таким же содержимм каки в моём комментрии ..

Потом методом fetch получил его и создал в html соответствующую разметку и в него вывел svg и сделал при наведении mouseover появление описание выбранной области

Плюсы такого подхода в том что при минимальном javascript коде мы получаем всю сразу карту с описанием  - **смотрим пример** без заваливания html кучей тегов

```js
function letsvg() {
  fetch('https://facejsonserver.000webhostapp.com/ ')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      let svg = "";
      for (let value in data) {
        let path = data[value];

        let ids = path['data-id'];
        let name = path['data-name'];
        let paths = path['data-path'];
        let description = path['data-description'];
        svg += `<path d="${paths}"
               data-name="${name}" 
               id="${ids}" 
               data-description="${description}"/>`;
      }
      map.innerHTML = svg;

    });
}

letsvg();

map.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  document.querySelector(".description").innerHTML =
    e.target.getAttribute("data-description");
})
```

```css
path:hover {
  fill: blue;
}

.grid {
  margin: 30px auto;
  max-width: 768px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.description {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <svg id="map" viewBox="0 0 1000 670"></svg>
  <div class="description"></div>
</div>
```

Для того что бы сгенерировать такой json я поступил таким образом

1. Вычистил не нужное теги g etc...
2. Методом forEach перебрал все path и все поместил в один массив

Выглядит это так:

```js
let paths = document.querySelectorAll("#map path");
let mass2 = [];

paths.forEach(function (path){
  let ids = path.getAttribute("id");
  let ds = path.getAttribute("d");
  let name = path.getAttribute("name");
  let description = "";

  mass2.push({
        "dataid":ids,
        "datapath":ds,
        "dataname":name ,
        "datadescription": description
  })
})
console.log(mass2)
```

И далее в кансоле выбираем Copy Object и потом создаём и переименовываем txt в json и вставляем ... ВСЁ  и потом уже руками дополняем description

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Alexandr_TT дополнил ответ

Comment: @Alexandr_TT карта в вопросе , а описание дописывал в ручную потому что не было его ... а оно по условию должно показываться и я брал его в yandex и вставлял уже в сгенерированную строку

Answer (score 0):

Держи) Поделюсь [своей работой](https://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/VPrOBr), может сможешь разобраться

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(0, 91, 187) 40%, rgb(255, 213, 0) 41%);
}

#Ukraine {
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

#KyivCity {
    fill: #3184EA;
    opacity: 0;
}

.mapBackground {
    fill: #74B2FF;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 0.5;
}

#Ukraine path:hover {
    fill: #97C2F8;
}

.pointerCircle {
    r: 2px;
    fill: #f00;
    stroke-linecap:square;  
    stroke-linejoin:bevel;  
    stroke-miterlimit:4;  
    stroke-dasharray:none;  
    stroke-dashoffset:0;  
    stroke-opacity:1;
}

.cityName {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    pointer-events: none;

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    fill: #000;
    text-shadow: white 1px 1px 0, white -1px -1px 0,
    white -1px 1px 0, white 1px -1px;
}


#Kiev:hover ~.cityKiev,
#KyivCity:hover ~.cityKiev,
#SevastopolCity:hover ~.citySevastopol,
#Crimea:hover ~.citySimferopol,
#Cherkasy:hover ~.cityCherkasy,
#Chernivtsi:hover ~.cityChernivtsi,
#Dnipropetrovsk:hover ~.cityDnipro,
#Donetsk:hover ~.cityDonetsk,
#Ivano-Frankivsk:hover ~.cityIvano-Frankivsk,
#Kharkiv:hover ~.cityKharkiv,
#Kherson:hover ~.cityKherson,
#Khmelnytskyi:hover ~.cityKhmelnytskyi,
#Kirovohrad:hover ~.cityKropyvnytskyi,
#Luhansk:hover ~.cityLuhansk,
#Lviv:hover ~.cityLviv,
#Mykolaiv:hover ~.cityMykolaiv,
#Odessa:hover ~.cityOdessa,
#Poltava:hover ~.cityPoltava,
#Rivne:hover ~.cityRivne,
#Sumu:hover ~.citySumu,
#Chernihiv:hover ~.cityChernihiv,
#Ternopil:hover ~.cityTernopil,
#Zakarpattia:hover ~.cityUzhhorod,
#Vinnytsia:hover ~.cityVinnytsia,
#Volyn:hover ~.cityLutsk,
#Zaporizhia:hover ~.cityZaporizhia,
#Zhytomyr:hover ~.cityZhytomyr{ 

    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но немного другая задача. При наведении у тебя появляются пути внутри этого же SVG, я же пытаюсь отобразить внешний блок.

Comment: @ДмитрийТюльпа там js нужен - так как ~ означает что рядом а hide совсем не рядом

Comment: @ДмитрийТюльпа Максим прав, без JS не получиться. В Вашем случаи svg и .hide эТо детки разного узла. Можно так попробовать `.uk-container:hover .hide {
  display: block;
} ` но это же не то что вам надо

Comment: @ДмитрийТюльпа: а что мешает поместить блок рядом и спозиционировать его, если уж пару строчек JS никак не подходят?

Comment: @UModeL  в svg не получиться div - ы с описанием запихнуть

Comment: @BlackStar1991: это почему? Разве `<foreignObject>` отменили?